# Pentaho multiple variables (iterating through variables)

Tags: loops, variables, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

my task is to generate a list of id's (done) and then each id individually needs to be passed as a variable into the where clause of the sql statement which then the generate a text file.

I have read all I can about using two transformation to pass the variables but I cannot get passed that error that multiple variables are being passed.

Please help !

I have two transformation one with set and the other get variables which are both in a job.

Answer (score 3):

What I think you're doing is reading the values you want to use as variables and then using a Set Variables step.

The Set Variables step can only accept 1 row of input. You cannot set a variable with more than one row.

What you should use instead is:

Main job:

```
Start --> Transformation 1 ---> Transformation 2 ---> Success
```

Transformation 1:

```
Table input --> Copy rows to result
```

Transformation 2:

```
Get variables ---> Table input --> Text file output
```

Transformation 2 (alternative):

```
Table input --> Text file output
```

Now, the details:

Transformation 1:

- Table input reads the values you need to pass to the 2nd SQL statement. For example, `select distinct id from some_table`.
- Copy rows to result passes those id's to the parent job.

Job:

- On the definition of Transformation 2 you need to check the box "execute for every input row" and on the Parameters map the incoming column from transformation 1 to a parameter name of transformation 2.

Transformation 2:

- You need to set a parameter, for example `id`, and then on the Set variables you read that variable (parameters in a transformation are read just as any other variable).
- Then the field you just created that gets the variable value can be inserted into the Table input step as a query parameter, not a variable. For example, `select * from data_table where id=?`, Choose the get variables step in the box "Insert data from step" and check the "execute for each row" checkbox.

Transformation 2 (alternative):

- You're not getting the variable into the input stream. Instead, you read it directly in your SQL statement, by typing something like `select * from data_table where id=${id}`. Remember to check the "Replace variables checkbox".

How it works:

- Transformation 1 reads the ids and passes them to the parent
- The parent job calls transformation 2 for each id it received, mapping the id field from transformation 1 to the id parameter of transformation 2
- Transformation 2 will get the parameter value and create a field that is then passed to the JDBC query.
- Transformation 2 (alternative): easier, just replace the id parameter verbatim directly into the SQL query.

An easier alternative: You don't need a job, just 1 transformation:

```
Table input 1 --> Table input 2 --> Text file output
```

Table input 1:

```
select id from some_table
```

Table input 2:

```
select * from data_table where id = ?
```

Select Table input 1 in the "Insert data from step" dropdown list, and check the "execute for each row" box.

How it works:

- Table input 1 generates a list of rows
- Table input 2 will run once for each row, replacing the question mark by the value of the 1st field in the input stream.

Final remarks:

- In the Job+Transformations approach the second SQL query runs inside a transformation. If it fails, the previous runs will have completely been output to the text file. It also gives you more choices when you want to change the algorithm or integrate it in larger codebases.
- The single transformation approach is easier to write and to run, also slightly faster as you only have 1 transformation to initialise and only once; but if it fails at some point there's no guarantee the text file created will have entire blocks of data. When the error occurs the transformation halts and the writing will stop at whatever stage it's at. It's also harder to debug if there's an error and not as flexible to later adapt.

My persona preference goes to the Job+Transformations approach in nearly all cases, even the simplest ones that could be handled by a single transformation.